# Evaluating the limit $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{m(m - 1)....(m - n + 1)}}{{(n - 1)!}}{x^n}$

Tags: limits

Evaluate:
$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{m(m - 1)....(m - n + 1)}}{{(n - 1)!}}{x^n}$$ where $x \in (-1,\ 1)$

I tried solving this as follows:
$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{mx}}{{n - 1}}\frac{{(m - 1)x}}{{n - 2}}.....\frac{{(m - n + 1)x}}{1}$$
$$=\{ \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{mx}}{{n - 1}}\} \{ \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{(m - 1)x}}{{n - 2}}\} .....\{ \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{(m - n + 1)x}}{1}\} $$

Now as the individual limit $\ \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{mx}}{{n - 1}}$ evaluates to $0$ can we say that the limit as whole tends to $0$?

I personally feel that this reasoning seems incorrect. Can someone please suggest an alternate way of tackling this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Not all the limits are $0$. For example the last one isn't.

Comment: Yes, that's what I felt while solving this problem. In fact, the last limit is $ - \infty $. However, I wasn't able to think of any other way to proceed.

Comment: Are you sure that you have typed in everything correctly?

Comment: Yes, I just cross-checked it with the question given in the book

Comment: What happens to the term ${m-n+1 \over n-1}x$ for large $n$? Try reversing the order of the denominators in your expansion above,

Comment: What number is m? Natural   or any real mumber?

Comment: If $m$ is a non-negative integer there is nothing to do.  Otherwise, use the ratio test on the associated **series**.

Comment: I was just asking.

Comment: @kmitov $m$ is any real number but NOT a positive integer

Comment: OK. Follow the suggestion of @AndréNicolas.

Answer (score 2):

Note that let $p_n = {m-n+1 \over n-1}x$ and  $\lim_n p_n = -x$.

Take $|x|< \beta < 1$, then for some $N$ we have $|p_n| < \beta$ for all $n \ge N$.

Then $|p_2\cdots p_n | \le |p_2 \cdots p_{N}| \beta^{n-N} $, hence $\lim_n p_2\cdots p_n = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the gamma function:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{{m(m - 1)....(m - n + 1)}}{{(n - 1)!}}\cdot x^n\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(m-k+1\right)}{{(n - 1)!}}\cdot x^n\right)=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\frac{m!}{(m-n)!}}{{(n - 1)!}}\cdot x^n\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\frac{m!}{(m-n)!}}{{(n - 1)!}}\cdot x^n\right)=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{nm!}{n!(m-n)!}\cdot x^n\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{x^nm!}{\Gamma(n)\Gamma(m-n+1)}\right)=$$
$$m!\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{x^n}{\Gamma(n)\Gamma(m-n+1)}\right)=m!\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{x^n}{\Gamma(n)(m-n)!}\right)$$

Comment: And what  hapens then?

Answer (score 0):

If $m$ is a positive integer the limit is evidently  zero.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I wanted to ask the same.

Comment: Welcome to the club of victims of downvoters !

Comment: What do you meen?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Basically, you are asking us to evaluate $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}n~{m\choose n}~x^n$ for $m\not\in\mathbb Z$ and $|x|<1$. The obvious choice would be [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).